# How to hide popups in order to programatically screenshot individual elements using Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter, frontend, screenshot

I'm trying to write a script that takes a tweet URL as input and uses Selenium in order to save the tweet as a screenshot. However, there's a couple of annoying popups that always appear when I do that - one asking me to log in, the other asking me to accept cookies. Normally, these are at the bottom of the screen. However, when I render just the specific div that corresponds to the tweet, they appear in the screenshot, like in this example:

[image: tweet with popups]

When I open the URL in a browser, I can manually hide the popups by changing their individual style and adding `display: none` or `visibility: collapse`, thus hiding the popups. But I don't know how to do it automatically with Selenium. Here is my code so far:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(<path-to-chromedriver.exe>, options=options)
driver.get('https://twitter.com/DanWolken/status/1491001309029277702')
sleep(2)

popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div')
popup.style = 'display: none'
sleep(1)

tweet = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(r'#react-root > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-13qz1uu.r-417010 > main > div > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-14lw9ot.r-jxzhtn.r-1ljd8xs.r-13l2t4g.r-1phboty.r-1jgb5lz.r-11wrixw.r-61z16t.r-1ye8kvj.r-13qz1uu.r-184en5c > div > section > div > div')
tweet.screenshot('test_tweet.png')
```

I've searched for an answer for a long time with no success. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution. Instead of changing element CSS using `popup.style = 'display: none'`, use

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#layers > div').style.display = 'none';")
```

I don't really understand the difference, but this does hide the popup properly. I'll leave this question up for a few days in case someone smarter comes along and offers a more intelligent explanation/solution.